# Inner join and stuff and search

Tags: sql-server, database, join, search, stored-procedures

I have seven tables:

1. Course
2. Course_Category
3. CourseCourse_Category (this is the bridging table between Course and Course_Category)
4. TrainerResourceRequirement
5. CourseTrainerResourceRequirement (this is the bridging table between Course and TrainerResourceRequirement)
6. UnitOfCompetency
7. CourseUnitOfCompetency (this is the bridging table between Course and UnitOfCompetency)

I am trying to build a search to list down the courses as per the selected Course_Category, TrainerResourceRequirement and UnitOfCompetency. I wrote a stored procedure which is as follows:

```
select CourseName,ClientCourseTitle,CourseDescription,IsTheCourseDisplayedOnWeb, IsTheCourseArchived, minCandidates, maxCandidates,
Course_Category_Name =
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CC.Course_Category_Name FROM Course_Category as CC
inner join CourseCourse_Category as CCC on CC.Course_CategoryID = CCC.Course_CategoryID
WHERE C.CourseID = CCC.CourseID and CC.Course_CategoryID = @Course_CategoryID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''),
TrainerResourceName =
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + TRR.TrainerResourceName FROM TrainerResourceRequirement as TRR
inner join CourseTrainerResourceRequirement as CTRR on TRR.TrainerResourceRequirementID=CTRR.TrainerResourceRequirementID
WHERE C.CourseID = CTRR.CourseID and TRR.TrainerResourceRequirementID = @TrainerResourceRequirementID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''),
UoC =
STUFF((SELECT ', ' +
UoC.UnitOfCompetencyCode + ' - ' + UoC.UnitOfCompetencyTitle as UnitofCompetencyTitle
FROM UnitOfCompetency as UoC
inner join CourseUnitOfCompetency as CUoC on UoC.UnitOfCompetencyID = CUoC.UnitOfCompetencyID
WHERE C.CourseID = CUoC.CourseID and UoC.UnitOfCompetencyID = @UnitOfCompetencyID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Course as C
order by CourseName
```

However, when I try to search the result turns out to be this:

[Search Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqjGj.png)

But the result should return only those rows which satisfies all the three conditions.

How should I restructure my query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What even is that SQL? I added some whitespace to it, to make it readable and it literally makes no sense. `UoC = WHERE c.CourseID = ...`? You have a subquery that starts an inner join, and then goes to a `CROSS JOIN`, with an `= STUFF`? That query will never run.

Comment: Oh God! It's not copied properly, I am sorry... My bad...

Comment: @Larnu Edited...!

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're asking but are you saying you only want to return results where a course_category name, trainerresourcename and uoc all exist?

Comment: @ZLK Yes! So whichever Course_Category Name, TrainerResourceName and UoC is selected by the user, and the Course which satisfies all three conditions, only that Course(s) should be displayed. But right now, it is displaying all courses and "NULL" where the conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: Then the simplest way to modify your current query is probably using `EXISTS` in a where clause 3 times then. e.g. `where exists (select 1 from othertable where othertable.id = maintable.id and othertable.col = @variable1) and exists (select 1 from othertable2...` Though there are a variety of ways you could tackle this in a similar manner (joins, cross apply, etc)